# Add records according to the quantity

Tags: sql, where-clause

the following result, I need to add records to the number of camp "cant"

```
igr_id  al_id   cant
31  60  1
40  146 1
43  88  2
45  110 1
```

where 2 column means that the amount should double registration 2, if three should double in 3 for example

```
igr_id  al_id   cant
31  60  1
40  146 1
43  88  1
45  110 1
43  88  1
```

So we have two records with

```
43  88  1
```

How does this query?

Comment: What DB you use (MSSQL,Oracle,MySQL,...)?

Answer (score 0):

select igr_id,  al_id, count(*) as cant from table group by igr_id, al_id;

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using solution the [Itzik Ben-Gan](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/47beb582-7bba-4f12-8e34-c3f9c6575c2e/duplicar-fila-en-base-a-l-nmero-que-contenga-un-campo-sql-2000?forum=sqlserveres)

creating one table Numero and using cross join.